# .htaccess to use shared ssl certificate

Tags: .htaccess, ssl, https

I have followed the recommendation of my host to write .htaccess to redirect visitors to my site to a domain with a security certificate. However, I am hoping to have my visitors see the original URL.

Consider:

example.com is a subdomain in the folder mydomain on my shared hosting.  username=user

The .htaccess code they recommend:

```
#RewriteEngine On 
#RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80 
#RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} folder 
#RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://secure100.inmotionhosting.com/~user/mydomain/$1 [R,L]
```

This works great - If I go to :
http://example.com/about-us

I get the secure domain:
https://secure100.inmotionhosting.com/~user/mydomain/about-us

However, I want my visitors to see:
https://example.com/about-us

Is this possible. I read that using [p] should show the original domain:

```
#RewriteEngine On 
#RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80 
#RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} folder 
#RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://secure100.inmotionhosting.com/~user/mydomain/$1 [P]
```

But this results in a 500 error.

I have considered only using .htaccess to serve up secure login and register pages, but this exposes my username to the public, which seems to be trading one security issue for another. Is a dedicated IP the only way to do this?

Comment: Perhaps [mod-proxy](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_proxy.html) isn't enabled on your server.

Comment: You can't do that without SSL certificate for your domain.

Comment: For that, you can use a free external DNS server/Cloud, like https://www.cloudflare.com/ or others offering SSL with sites that do not have one.

Comment: I will ask about mod-proxy. If I buy a SSL certificate, this will work?

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that adding ssl to a shared hosting account is pretty common. There may be a way to do this the direction I was heading, but it was much easier to pay the hosting company to add it. I include this as not necessarily an answer to the .htaccess question, but as an alternative path for others that may find themselves in the same place.